# Batch script access denied even with admin privileges

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64

I have a batch script in Windows7 to update the `hosts` file that fails.
I am logged as a user with administrative rights.

Even if I run the script with the "Run as administrator" option I get `Access denied. 0 files copied` when executing this part of the script:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%

REM create changing part of hosts file...   
if exist %temp%\temp.txt del %temp%\temp.txt
echo %ip% myproxy >> %temp%\temp.txt  

REM check this...
set hostpath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

REM add static part of hosts file
type "%hostpath%\hosts-static" >> %temp%\temp.txt

REM replace hosts file
copy /y %temp%\temp.txt "%hostpath%\hosts"

ipconfig /flushdns
netsh interface IP delete arpcache
pause
```

I also tried to create a shortcut and set the "Advanced -> Run as Administrator" option but no luck.

If I open a cmd shell as Administrator and then run the script from there everything works fine, but no way of running it directly double-clicking on the file (or its link).
Any idea?

---

EDIT:

- added the whole script.
- I tried creating a shortcut for the following command to execute as Administrator

  C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c script.bat

and it is also failing.
From the same shortcut (without arguments) I can open a window where I can execute the batch correctly. I really cannot see why.

Comment: Working fine on my machine with Admin privileges. Got an `Access is denied` without it. I ran it by double clicking. Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Try restarting your system, seems like a process has an active lock on the file

Comment: Try restarting your PC and if this doesn't work try giving your system more control or run the batch file with admin

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a late response, but just solved this issue with a very straightforward solution so I thought I'd share:

Using [**ICACLS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) you can modify access control lists (ACLs) to bypass access denied errors.
Run the following command:

```
ICACLS C:\path\to\batch\file\directory\* /C
```

the parameter /C tells the batch file to bypass access denied errors. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `attrib -r -s -h -a "%hostpath%\hosts"` before your `copy` command.  If any file is attributed +r, +s, or +h, you'll get "Access is denied" if you try to overwrite it using `copy`.

Comment: I tried to add the line in the script but I still get the error.

Comment: @ValentinaDiGiacomo Could be virus scanner software preventing `hosts` from being overwritten?  Try disabling your virus scanner / Internet security software, CryptoPrevent, etc?  Also, try [BatchGotAdmin](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/home/BatchGotAdmin) to force admin elevation.

Comment: May be. Unfortunately it is the company's firewall and antivirsus, so I cannot change the settings.